# Unable to plot obtain realizations of Gamma distribution variant

Tags: data-visualization, density-function, gamma-distribution

I have the probability density function (pdf) for $\sigma^2 = 1/\phi$, where $\phi\sim \text{Gamma}(a, b)$. I am trying to simulate 1000 realizations of $\phi$ and then plot a histogram using the pdf obtained. However, my plot seems to be incorrect. I am posting this here instead of StackOverflow, for I feel that there is something wrong with my logic rather than code -

```
from scipy.special import gamma

def phi(sigma, alpha, beta):
    return (((1/sigma**2)**(alpha-1))*np.exp(-1*(1/sigma**2)/beta)*(1/sigma**4))/(beta**alpha)*gamma(alpha)

shape, scale = 10,10
s = 1/np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)
ans = phi(s,10, 10)

plt.hist(ans)
```

Here is the output -

[image]

The reason, I am confused is that when I work with a generic Gamma distribution with shape, scale = 10,10 I get a histogram with many more bins -

```
import numpy as np
shape, scale = 10,10
s = np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special as sps
plt.hist(s)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code generates large numbers and takes large negative powers of them, which ought to produce really tiny values.  The plot looks accurate.  What do you hope the code would do?

Comment: @whuber - Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question.